# How to override methods in Dispatch.php

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm hard coding the $connection and $queue in over 10 files so I'm trying to clean that up. My first thought is to create some helpers that I can access in all of these files. However, I don't need those methods/variable available throughout my entire app. Instead, it would make most sense to place them in the ShouldQueue class. Any thoughts on the proper way to do this?

```
namespace App\Listeners\User;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Log;

class CreateJenzUser implements ShouldQueue
{

 use InteractsWithQueue;

 public $connection = 'sqs_high';

 public $queue = 'portal_high.fifo';

 //Would rather use
 public $connection = $highConnection;

 public function handle(UserBeingCreated $event)
 {
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

It turns out Laravel is creating a new instance of CreateJenzUser without the constructor.

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php - line 479

```
/**
 * Create the listener and job for a queued listener.
 *
 * @param  string  $class
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $arguments
 * @return array
 */
protected function createListenerAndJob($class, $method, $arguments)
{
    $listener = (new ReflectionClass($class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

    return [$listener, $this->propagateListenerOptions(
        $listener, new CallQueuedListener($class, $method, $arguments)
    )];
}
```

Just need to figure out how to override this method.

Comment: what do you mean by place them in the ShouldQueue class? ShouldQueue is an interface

Comment: So would it be better to just place them in the helper?

Comment: I would extend a class. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would make a parent [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and extend it from all the classes that needs to use the queue. You can specify all the method that you must implement as abstract methods in the parent class so you do not need to implement the `ShouldQueue` interface.

So, the parent class will look like

```
abstract class Queue
{
     use InteractsWithQueue;

     protected $connection = 'sqs_high';

     protected $queue = 'portal_high.fifo';

     // list here all the methods in your ShouldQueue interface
     abstract protected function handle(UserBeingCreated $event);
}
```

Then the child class:

```
class CreateJenzUser extends Queue
{

    protected function handle(UserBeingCreated $event)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you need to keep the interface (for type hint check for example) you can extend and implement in the same time. So, the child class in this case will look like:

```
class CreateJenzUser extends Queue implements ShouldQueue
{

    protected function handle(UserBeingCreated $event)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

The `Queue` class may not need to be abstract in this case. However, that depends on how you want to design. If you have some methods that you want to call from the parent but define in the child you can still keep it as an abstract class.

Comment: I'd be a little weary of removing the interface completely.  I think you'd still want to implement `ShouldQueue`, at the very least, with your abstract class as it may cause some problems later on when this class fails any `instanceof ShouldQueue` checks.

Comment: sure, you can do both. You can extend and implement in the same time. Let me update my answer

Comment: I'm not able to update set variables though. I've tried to update them using methods from a trait in the constructor but no luck. If I set up the abstract class, will this allow me to update the variables?

Comment: @DavidLapham can you please provide some details (with codes) on what you tried and what did not work? That would help me give you a better answer?

Comment: Actually, just a quick update, I did discover that Laravel is using newInstanceWithoutConstructor() to grab the variables but not run the constructor so that makes sense now why I can't update them.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like that all those classes share code, that should be refactored. Probably the best option would be to [extract class](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) and then pass it as a dependency  in the constructors of classes, which need that behavior.

You should also consider the fact, that `trait` is basically interpretator assisted copy-paste. You are just using a language structure to hide that code duplication.

> **P.S.**
>   Don't use `extends` to fix this. The "extends" keyword should be read as "is a special subtype of". And user is **not** a special type of queue ... frankly, some could see it as an insult.

Comment: Didn't even think about a trait. Smart. 

So I've created the trait but when trying to set the variable with a method it errors out because you can't set a default value like that (just learned that the hard way). I tried updating the values in the construct  but it looks like its not taking the values. I know I'm getting closer!

Comment: @DavidLapham both the connection should be passed in constructor as dependencies. As for the "computed default values", it looks like what you would need is a factory class set up in the DI container config, which would retrieve both of the "high priority" values. As it stands, it seems to me, that you code suffers from significant [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Looks like I need to do a little more OOP research. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: ... I wonder, why was this downvoted, did I say something wrong?